# React - Focus on element mechanism

Tags: reactjs, setfocus

What's the best approach to build a mechanism to set the focus on elements in an entire app from different parts.

*Example scenario:* There is a button (somewhere in the app) and user clicks on that button and another component (which is somewhere else in the tree) gets mounted (or the component may be already mounted and present) and then automatically focus moves to one specific element in the component.

**Notes:**
We all know handling the focus in React apps is not easy. I have already a solution but want to know what's the best solution out there that community is using.

My solution ([here is a demo](https://vnk43.csb.app)) is creating a context and updating the value based on an ID and components listen for the context value and do the focus.

Comment: A context is also how I would handle this, you could an id up with the click event to the new component so that you won't even need to hard code anything. Some form of ref could also solve the problem but I believe a context is clean, even with the bad press they get, contexts are very useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: Correct, added a simple example to my question.

Comment: Yeah looks decent to me, especially if you only use this sparingly over yor project as I can see keeping up with ID names becoming tiring, I may even suggest passing a prop into both SomeButton and SomeInput so that you can link them where they are used using the same variable.

Comment: Very nice idea @JamesGill, I updated some of the code and cleaned up a bit more

Comment: You could always set up redux where you would hold information about which component should be focused on in whatever path and simply extract it from the redux store state

Comment: The example that I provided should be better as it works out of the box without depending on Redux with similar mechanism.